# Implement UITableView with fixed headers and fixed columns

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a UITablewView with fixed headers and a fixed set of columns. Basically, something like this:

http://www.novasoftware.com/download/jquery_fixedtable/jQuery_FixedTable_Demo.htm

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Should add I'm only displaying text content in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` does not support multiple columns.

I recommend using a `UIWebView` or possibly a `UIScrollView` to display data in such a format.

Comment: Can't it still be a single column, but each cell is actually made up of multiple columns (of course you'd have to make sure to get the alignment of everything correct).

Comment: @nsx241: Yes, but at that point I believe you're better off with a scrollview since you aren't using any of the built in functionality of a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).  (Assuming you're targeting iOS 6 or later, use UICollectionView

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Actually at this point, I would suggest UICollectionView, as Apple hired Alan Quartermain, and apparently he managed to get the idea into the real SDK.